# Jquery position of dialog on top of <li>

Tags: modal-dialog

I created code to show jquery dialog on click of a div. Right now dialog pops at 5 points after the click position.

I am trying to display dialog from top line of li, it means the top border of li should be aligned with top border of dialog. Could some one point me to right logic to find out how to open dialog by getting li top border position.

```
  <div class="editionDetailAction">Action for Item 1</div>
<div class="editionDetailAction">Action for Item 2</div>
<div class="editionDetailAction">Action for Item 3</div>
<div class="editionDetailAction">Action for Item 4</div>



<div id="actionsPopup">
    <ul><li><a href="http://www.google.com">Add xyz</a></li></ul>
    <ul><li>Manage xyz</li></ul>
    <ul><li>Show xyz</li></ul>
</div>


.editionDetailAction { width: 130px; height: 30px; border: solid 1px #ddd; }
.actionsPopup .ui-dialog-titlebar { display:none; }



$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.editionDetailAction').click(function (e) {
        $("#actionsPopup").dialog("option", { position: [e.pageX+5, e.pageY+5] });
    });

    $("#actionsPopup").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,  
dialogClass: 'actionsPopup',
        maxWidth:100,
                    maxHeight: 100,
                    width: 100,
        height: 80,
resizable: false,


    });
    $(".editionDetailAction").bind("click", function () {
        $("#actionsPopup").dialog('open'); 
    });
    $(".actionsPopup").bind("mouseover", function () {
        $("#actionsPopup").dialog('open');
    }); $(".actionsPopup").bind("mouseleave", function () {
        $("#actionsPopup").dialog('close');
    });

    $(".editionDetailAction").bind("mouseleave", function () {
        $("#actionsPopup").dialog('close'); 
    });


   });
```

Comment: Using this for testing: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/DZm9d/ You want the Menu to appear aligned with the `li` right? But you're setting the position based on the mouse click position?

Comment: Twisty, I am trying to align to li and could not succeed so I temporarily added positions based on mouse click. Its a temporary code. I am trying to get li top position and then change x and y accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.editionDetailAction').click(function() {
    var pos = $(this).position();
    $("#actionsPopup").dialog("option", {
        position: [pos.left+5, pos.top+5]
    });
});
```

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/DZm9d/1/

Comment: Thanks alot.. Modified bit as per my requirement but logic is correct and very useful.